# Excel DATEVALUE function not working for today's date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to convert today's date to number value in Excel cell Formula.

```
=DATEVALUE(TODAY())
```

Returns:

> #VALUE!

But if i use `=DATEVALUE("03-12-2012")`, returns:

> 41246

Could anyone please tell me how to get date number value of **today's date**....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(TODAY(),"YYYY-MM-DD"))
```

The `DATEVALUE` function requires the input to be in the correct format.
The `TODAY` function returns the date in the format of the regional settings.
Therefore you format the date in a format the `DATEVALUE` function can understand.

The `TODAY` function actually return the value of the current date, so putting it into a `DATEVALUE` is just running in circles.

You should only need to use:

```
=TODAY()
```

And then format the cell to be a numeric format rather than a date format.

Answer (score 2):

Don't quite understand you, `DATEVALUE()` convert a STRING to DATETIME. It doesn't convert a DATETIME into number.  In Excel, DATETIME and number is inter-changeable. You only need to change the display format for a date and it can be shown as number (and vice versa). You can also do a `=TODAY() * 5` and it will work.
Any DATETIME in excel is stored as DAY.Hour format (with 0.0 being 00 Jan 1900).

Answer (score 0):

Try this =DAY(N(TODAY())). This will return the day value of the current date(Current date is automatically captured here)

Answer (score -1):

This will work:

```
=VALUE(TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyymmdd"))
```

Result:

```
20130130
```

Regards

Answer (score -2):

```
=N(TODAY())

=N(NOW())
```

returns the date & time

Comment: Please don't post just code, explain it, so the OP can learn from your answer.